# Hangfire Enqueue Fire-and-Forget Jobs

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, hangfire

I'm facing an issue with Hangfire Enqueue Job in .NET core

My application is already running on the staging server and also implemented some hangfire jobs, we implement a new hangfire enqueue job on the local server and we used the staging server connection string, when we run the Data Successfully inserted in hangfire's Job & State Table, first it scheduled and after that, it failed with an exception

```
Can not change the state to 'Processing': target method was not found.
```

and

```
{
    "FailedAt": "2023-08-14T09:15:00.0753909Z",
    "ExceptionType": "System.InvalidOperationException",
    "ExceptionMessage": "The type `MyFightbook.Web.Services.InvoiceUpdateService.InvoiceDataService` does not contain a method with signature `RefundApplicationFee(String, String, Int32, Int32)`",
    "ExceptionDetails": "System.InvalidOperationException: The type `MyFightbook.Web.Services.InvoiceUpdateService.InvoiceDataService` does not contain a method with signature `RefundApplicationFee(String, String, Int32, Int32)`\r\n   at Hangfire.Storage.InvocationData.DeserializeJob()"
}
```

Please help me resolve this issue.
Thanks in advance